# Is it possible to use WHERE clause in same query as PARTITION BY?

Tags: teradata

I need to write SQL that keeps only the minimum 5 records per each identifiable record in a table.  For this, I use `partition by` and delete all records where the value returned is greater than 5.  When I attempt to use the WHERE clause in the same query as the `partition by` statement, I get the error "Ordered Analytical Functions not allowed in WHERE Clause".  So, in order to get it to work, I have to use three subqueries.  My SQL looks ilke this:

```
delete mydb.mytable where (field1,field2) in
(
    select field1,field2 from
    (
        select field1,field2,
        Rank() over
        (
            partition BY field1
            order by field1,field2
        ) n 
        from mydb.mytable
    ) x
    where n > 5
)
```

The innermost subquery just returns the raw data.  Since I can't use WHERE there, I wrapped it with a subquery, the purpose of which is to 1) use WHERE to get records greater than 5 in rank and 2) select only field1 and field2.  The reason why I select only those two fields is so that I can use the IN statement for deleting those records in the outermost query.

It works, but it appears a bit cumbersome.  I'd like to consolidate the inner two subqueries into a single subquery.  Is this possible?

Comment: Can't comment directly to your question, but I think you should consider using `ROW_NUMBER()` rather than `RANK()`, in case there are any "ties".

Comment: I will look into row_number.  There won't be any ties, though, because the comparisons are done only on unique indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use the `QUALIFY` clause which is the `HAVING` clause for Window Aggregate functions. Below is my take on what you are trying to accomplish.

***Please do not run this SQL directly against your production data without first testing it.***

```
/* Physical Delete */
DELETE TGT
  FROM MyDB.MyTable TGT
 INNER JOIN
       (SELECT Field1
             , Field2
        FROM MyDB.MyTable
        QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() (PARTITION BY Field1, ORDER BY Field1,2)
              > 5
       ) SRC
    ON TGT.Field1 = SRC.Field1
   AND TGT.Field2 = SRC.Fileld2

/* Logical Delete */
UPDATE TGT
  FROM MyDB.MyTable TGT
     ,
       (SELECT Field1
             , Field2
        FROM MyDB.MyTable
        QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() (PARTITION BY Field1, ORDER BY Field1,2)
              > 5
       ) SRC
   SET Deleted = 'Y'
    /* RecordExpireDate = Date - 1 */
 WHERE TGT.Field1 = SRC.Field1
   AND TGT.Field2 = SRC.Fileld2
```